# Cannot get WP CLI to work with docker: mbind not permitted

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I cant get this to work. Im not sure whats going on, I have searched all over and cannot find any information on this and hope to find someone here. I am trying to use WP CLI on docker-compose and run some commands on boot.

So far I have tried to install it manually on an image build which does work but then I get some errors so cannot use it. eg like this.

Does anyone know why this may not be working for me (i think permission errors?) and what the right way to do this is?

The error on the SQL logs are 'mbind operation not permitted'
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This kinds of errors happens when MySQL tries to do operations on NUMA (non-uniform memory access), but this kinds of operations are blocked by Docker.

NUMA are used on servers with more then one group of memory per processor, and MySQL have a strange past related to it.

Try another image version like `mysql:5.7` or `mariadb`.

```yaml
version: '3.0'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
```